# How to do Null value check in Java script?

Tags: javascript

in jsp i am writing java script. Please help me how to do null check in javascript? i have drop down list. onchange some action should happen. pleae find below code.

```
<select onchange="openPage(this.value)">
```

here some times this.value can be null. simply i need to do null check.when it is not null then only it should call openPage() method. please help me how to solve?

Thanks!

Comment: if(this.value != null) . sorry code is missing.

Comment: `<select onchange="javascript:if(this.value !== null) openPage(this.value)">` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(this.value == undefined)
```

Do check as above

Comment: i was going to say, i've never seen the `is` operator in JS. Am i missing something here??

Answer (score 3):

the simplest way to do this, and it covers cases where the value is an empty string, false, null, zero or undefined is:

```
if(!this.value) {
   //this will only execute if this.value is null, undefined, zero, empty string or false
}
```

Hope that helps. Obviously this isn't a good idea when it comes to working with boolean values (where you genuinely expect true or *false* values), but for 99% of the time it's great :)

Comment: !'' is returns true but you said for empty strings too ?

Comment: Argh, Boolean logic fail! What I meant was it will only execute if `this.value` **is** null, undefined etc. The code is correct, the comment was not. Updated answer to reflect your observation. Thanks

Comment: I always hate to check null,undefined and empty strings together in javascript :). It is better to encapsulate these checks in a function.

Comment: I just like to embrace the truthy/falsey nature of JavaScript. For most instances empty strings, null or undefined require similar handling - consider `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` in .NET. So I find it makes sense to group the logically as above, keeps your code quite terse as well

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
if(this.value != null)
```